# Monitoring Network traffic in Windows Mobile 6.5 using C#?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile-6.5, windows-mobile-5.0

I need to monitor Network Traffic of every application used in Windows Mobile 6.5 device using c#.

I really don't know where to start and how to start.

After searching in google, i found Netlog can be helpful for this scenario.

Any Ideas?

Please suggest me.

Thanks,

Balu

Answer (score 0):

Yes netlog is an example provided within Windows CE Platformbuilder.

When you look at the source code, you will see that netlog is a 'driver' DLL and netlogctl is used to control the DLL.

I fear that architecture is not to be re-build using C#. You cannot write native driver DLLs using C#.

BUT, you can also use iphlpapi, see my netstat example: http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2013/09/24/mobile-development-netstat-know-your-devices-open-ports/.

You get an overall stat:

```
======= TCP statistics ========
Retransmission timeout (min/max): Van Jacobson's Algorithm: 300/120000
            max connnections: -1
                 active open: 69
                passive open: 196
             failed attempts: 0
          established resets: 243
         current established: 20
                 segments in: 134380
                segments out: 130900
      retransmitted segments: 175
                   in errors: 0
                  out resets: 861
             num connections: 26
======= UDP statistics ========
                in datagrams: 13771
                   in errors: 0
                   num ports: 3353
               num addresses: 7
               out datagrams: 887
```